# Debug only server-side code and not script?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a simple way of only attaching the debugger to server-side code when debugging an asp .net app? I want to, for now, ignore all JS errors and unhanled exceptions. IDE is Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare this on your javasript

```
function errorHandler(msg,url,lno){ 
   return (true);
} 

window.onerror = errorHandler;
```

That way all the javascript errors are not shown at all.

Comment: Nice. Spot on, thanks a lot for that. Surprised it takes a work around though and no 'proper' way of doing it.

Comment: @DeeMac On code behind you can also call the `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` to attache the debugger at some point.